# Joomla render full article by id with "JModelLegacy getInstance article"

Tags: php, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I'm stuck trying to get joomla full article to render in a tab. The tab is working. I just can´t render the article content. This is where I am now.

This is helper.php

```
public static function getArticle($articleId)

{

JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$article = $model->getItem((int) $articleId);

$fullarticle = $item->fulltext;

$itemsHtml = '<div>'. $fullarticle .'</div>';

return $itemsHtml;
}
```

And this is in default.php

```
  ...code...
  else if ($list_of_tabs['use'][$i][0] == 'article'){            
    echo '<div class="tab-pane '.$active.'" id="'.$i.$rid.'">'.
            modJpTabsHelper::getArticle($list_of_tabs['article'][$i], $params) .
         '</div>';
  }
  ...code...
```

If you need more info. Don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve: to write your own Joomla! extension which displays articles in a tab or you just need to display your J! articles in a tab?

If it's a latter, then there are already some nice and free (as in a "free bear") add-ons written just for that.

Comment: Yes I am trying to write my own Joomla extension. Im sorry to be rude here but there is, of course, a reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the model part of an MVC as a thing to render.
You should use the MVC system - using a controller to gathering the model and the view, and then you can render the model with the attached view, via the controller.

So you use something like (I've not tested this - you will need to correct it).

```
$filter=array('id' => $i->query['id']);
$options=array('filter_fields' => $filter,'ignore_request' => true);

$ctl = new ContentModelController();
$view = $ctl->getView( 'Article');
$model = $ctl->getModel( 'Article','',$options);
```

you may need to set params from application, eg..

```
$model->setState('params', JApplication::getInstance('site')->getParams());
```

then continue

```
$view->setModel( $model, true );
$result = $view->display();
```

Make sure that you have JLoader::import'ed any classes/classpaths - j. tends to fail silently if they aren't found, which can be difficult to trace.

Sorry, it's only a partial solution - but hopefully it may put you on the right track.

Comment: I had to use the sql solution since I had a deadline. But I believe this is a better solution so I will give it a try when I got time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here was the problem:

```
$fullarticle = $item->fulltext;
```

Article object from model was in variable $article not $item:

```
$article = $model->getItem((int) $articleId);
```

So getting property fulltext from article object should be:

```
$fullarticle = $article->fulltext;
```